# How do I bind and unbinddirectional for a StringProperty in a ComboBox javaFX?

Tags: javafx, combobox, binding

This is how I unbindBiDirectional from a class FamilyMember that contains a string variable called 'txtName'. I unbind the old value and clear it, and then bind the new value.

Unbinding:

```
((TreeItem<FamilyMember>)oldValue).getValue().nameProperty().unbindBidirectional(txtName.textProperty());
txtName.clear();
```

Binding:

```
txtName.setText(((TreeItem<FamilyMember>)newValue).getValue().nameProperty().getValue());
((TreeItem<FamilyMember>)newValue).getValue().nameProperty().bindBidirectional(txtName.textProperty());
```

But im confused as to how to do this for a ComboBox. My ComboBox is for selecting a gender with 3 options as strings, (ComboBox), Male, Female and Other. How can I achieve the above using a ComboBox with String Property instead?

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: comboBox has a value property (suspect that your description of what you _really_ want to achieve is incomplet, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> genderComboBox;
    @FXML
    private Label selectedGenderLabel;

    private Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Add items:
        genderComboBox.getItems().addAll("Male", "Female", "Other");

        // Bind selection of combo box to string property:
        selectedGenderLabel.textProperty().bind(genderComboBox.valueProperty());
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleUnbindBtnClick() {
        // Un-bind and clear:
        selectedGenderLabel.textProperty().unbind();
        selectedGenderLabel.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleBindBtnClick() {
        // Make a random selection:
        genderComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(random.nextInt(3));

        // Re-bind:
        selectedGenderLabel.textProperty().bind(genderComboBox.valueProperty());
    }
}
```

FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="genderComboBox" />
      <Label text="Selected Gender:" />
      <Label fx:id="selectedGenderLabel" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleUnbindBtnClick" text="Unbind" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBindBtnClick" text="Bind" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: you can (and should - the rule is: avoid path bindings whenever possible) bind to the combo's value - it's guaranteed to be the same as the selectedItem. And I don't why the intermediate stringProperty?

Comment: Okay, thank you. I removed the intermediate StringProperty and changed to valueProperty(). Can you please tell me what can go wrong when i use getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()? Or where to read about that rule?

Comment: the general problem with path properties is that you'll have to guard against changes of all parent properties and re-wire the binding/listener if it changes. Here that would be listening to the selectionModelProperty and update the binding to the selectedItem - doesn't happen very frequently, but without the code is brittle.